# Cannot use placeholder in static factory method creating a SpringLiquibase bean

Tags: spring, liquibase, applicationcontext

Spring 3.1.0 with Liquibase 2.0.5 running on Glassfish 2.1.1 - From a long gone colleague I have inherited this applicationContext.xml which constructs a SpringLiquibase bean this way:

```
<bean id="liquibaseConfiguratore" factory-method="createLiquibaseBean" class="com.whatever.LiquibaseFactory">
    <constructor-arg name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceConfiguratore"/>
    <constructor-arg name="changeLog" value="classpath:liquibase/configuratore-db-changelog.xml"/>
    <constructor-arg name="propFileName" value="/opt/whatever/ec_properties.properties"/>
</bean>
```

where LiquibaseFactory is a factory and the bean produced by the static method *createLiquibaseBean* has class

```
com.whatever.CustomLiquibase extends liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase
```

Now I need to parameterize the changeLog value, so that my bean declaration becomes:

```
<bean id="liquibaseConfiguratore" factory-method="createLiquibaseBean" class="com.whatever.LiquibaseFactory"> 
    <constructor-arg name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceConfiguratore"/>
    <constructor-arg name="changeLog" value="${tgo.liquibase.changelog.filename}"/>
    <constructor-arg name="propFileName" value="/opt/whatever/ec_properties.properties"/>
</bean>
```

In order to set the correct value for the parameter, I browse the source of SpringLiquibase and I see that the String changeLog:

```
/**
 * Sets a Spring Resource that is able to resolve to a file or classpath resource.
 * An example might be <code>classpath:db-changelog.xml</code>.
 */
public void setChangeLog(String dataModel) { ... }
```

After reading this, I put the original string inside my properties file.

```
tgo.liquibase.changelog.filename=classpath:liquibase/configuratore-db-changelog.xml
```

and declare the props as:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:///opt/whatever/custom_properties.properties" />
```

But the bean fails during creation. Error message is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibaseConfiguratore' defined in class path resource [spring/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: Cannot find parser that supports classpath:liquibase/configuratore-db-changelog.xml
    at 
.....
Caused by: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: Cannot find parser that supports classpath:liquibase/configuratore-db-changelog.xml
    at liquibase.parser.ChangeLogParserFactory.getParser(ChangeLogParserFactory.java:61)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:107)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:262)
```

Apparently the parser is found when there is a plain string in the XML. The moment I put a placeholder, the parser ain't there to be found. But it looks like the placeholder is resolved correctly, at least on screen...

I have tried some variations:

- put file:/absolute/path/to/configuratore-db-changelog.xml in the property
- put classpath*:liquibase/configuratore-db-changelog.xml in the property
- put properties 'index=0,1,2' instead of 'name' inside tag constructor.arg

But the problem is still there.

**How can I use a placeholder to specify the changeLog parameter?**

HERE IS THE COMPLETE STACK TRACE:

`[#|2014-06-25T09:19:54.860+0200|SEVERE|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web|_ThreadID=12;_ThreadName=pool-1-thread-6;_RequestID=36e46602-c248-4e54-844e-6e5e11225bb8;|WebModule[/FastwebSme]PWC1275: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibaseConfiguratore' defined in class path resource [spring/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: Cannot find parser that supports classpath:liquibase/configuratore-db-changelog.xml
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4632)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5312)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:353)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.LifecycleStarter.doRun(LifecycleStarter.java:58)
        at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase.runSync(RunnableBase.java:304)
        at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase.run(RunnableBase.java:341)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: Cannot find parser that supports classpath:liquibase/configuratore-db-changelog.xml
        at liquibase.parser.ChangeLogParserFactory.getParser(ChangeLogParserFactory.java:61)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:107)
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:262)
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:245)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
        ... 24 more
|#]`

AND HERE IS LIQUIBASEFACTORY:

```
package com.whatever.util;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class LiquibaseFactory {

private static boolean enabled = !StringUtils.equals(
        System.getProperty("liquibase.disable"), "true");

private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LiquibaseFactory.class);

public static CustomLiquibase createLiquibaseBean(DataSource dataSource,
        String changeLog, String propFileName) {

    log.info("dataSource is " + dataSource);
    log.info("changeLog is " + changeLog);
    log.info("propFileName is " + propFileName);

    CustomLiquibase customLiquibase = null;
    if (enabled) {

        log.info("creating customLiquibase ENABLED");

        customLiquibase = new CustomLiquibase(propFileName);
        customLiquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        customLiquibase.setChangeLog(changeLog);

    } else {

        log.warn("Liquibase has been disabled");

        log.warn("\n\n" + StringUtils.repeat("*", 80));
        log.warn(StringUtils.repeat("*", 80) + "\n\n");

    }
    return customLiquibase;
}

}
```

AND HERE IS CUSTOMLIQUIBASE:

```
package com.whatever.util;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils;

public class CustomLiquibase extends SpringLiquibase {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger
        .getLogger(CustomLiquibase.class);

public CustomLiquibase(String propertiesName) {

    super();
    LOGGER.info("propertiesName is " + propertiesName);

    Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(new File(propertiesName));
    try {
        LOGGER.info("resource is " + resource);

        Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
        Map<String, String> ps = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (Object key : props.keySet()) {
            Object value = props.get(key);
            if (value != null) {
                ps.put(key.toString(), value.toString());
            }
        }
        this.setChangeLogParameters(ps);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("", ex);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Can you post the complete source code of `LiquibaseFactory` and a more complete stack-trace?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I realized my description was incorrect. I have changed both text and title. LiquibaseFactory has a static method that invokes the SpringLiquibase constructor and those "constructor-arg"s are actually the parameters for the static method.

Comment: What is the source code of `LiquibaseFactory`?

Comment: whoops - there it goes... I enclose also CustomLiquibase.

Comment: I've tested your code and I'm not seeing the exception... I'd suggest testing your app both ways (with and without placeholder) and debug to see what kind of parsers are used.

Comment: Good luck! If you find anything unusual or interesting in your investigation you can post here.

Comment: I found out that Jetty works fine. Problem only with Glassfish. Gotta check the libraries.